# Calculate point coordinates after image rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, image-processing

So I have two rectangle pictures with known Resolution

On the first image we have a point on $(900, 300)$ $x,y$ pixel coordinate (guessed number, not exactly).

The second picture is rotated by $15^\circ$. Width and Hight of this picture is increased, because its rotated $15^\circ$.

Is there a way to calculate the same point position on the 2nd image with the known information? If yes, how?

Comment: Where is the image rotated about? Where is the coordinate origin?

Comment: @K.Jiang The 2nd picture is rotated 15 degrees clockwise. The coordinate is just the x,y pixel coordinate on the picture

Comment: You can use a rotation matrix if you are familiar with this

Comment: @automatikz "rotated 15 degrees clockwise"... about where? The bottom left corner (which I assume is the coordinate origin)? The center? It's unclear from the question.

Comment: @K.Jiang Its rotated from the center I guess. Just a normal image rotation with a picture editing software

Comment: Ok, what are the coordinates of the center?

Comment: @DavidQuinn I have read that it should work with the rotation matrix, but have not found an example calculation that fits my example with a rectangle

Comment: @K.Jiang The center coordinates of the 1st picture are 600x315, from the 2nd picture 661x460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we are rotating about the center of the image, we will use that as our origin. The relative coordinates of the unrotated point are $(900, 300) - (600, 315) = (300, -15)$. Since we are rotating the point clockwise, we can use the rotation matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\
-\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

as the transformation matrix. Note that $(1, 0)$ gets transformed to $(\cos \theta, -\sin \theta)$ as expected. Here, $\theta = 15^\circ$. So, the image is

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\cos (15^\circ) & \sin (15^\circ) \\
-\sin (15^\circ) & \cos (15^\circ)
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
300 \\
-15
\end{pmatrix} \approx \begin{pmatrix}
294 \\
-74
\end{pmatrix}$$

when rounded to the nearest integers. Relative to the original origin, the coordinates of the image are about $(600, 315) + (294, -74) = \boxed{(894, 241)}$.

**EDIT**: Update with new information.

It was given that the coordinates of the (untransformed) center relative to the lower-left of the new image are $(661, 440)$. So, relative to the lower-left of the new image, the point is at $(661, 440) + (294, -74) = \boxed{(955, 366)}$.

Comment: What if rotation is 15 degree counterclockwise? So -15 degrees

Comment: Then just enter the matrix with $\theta = -15^\circ$. The transformation matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} \cos (15^\circ) & -\sin (15^\circ) \\ \sin (15^\circ) & \cos (15^\circ) \end{pmatrix}$. Can you take it from here?